# Convert UIImage to byte array in swift

Tags: ios, swift

How can I convert a UIimage into a Byte Array, so I can upload it into my web service?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This can be done with one or two lines of code

```
guard let image = UIImage(named: "someImage"),
      let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) else { return }

// OR

guard let image = UIImage(named: "someImage"),
      let data = image.pngData() else { return }
```

In the first instance, the number should range from 0.0 to 1.0 and sets the jpeg quality.
PNG is lossless so there is no need for a compression quality value but be aware that the file size can be about 10 times higher

`--- update ---`

Updated for Swift 5.1

Comment: Does `unpackedImage` refer to `image`? Or is there another process that needs to be implemented between creating `image` and creating `data`?

Comment: Sorry for that, `UIImage()` initialiser usually returns an optional, obviously it has to be unwrapped since the `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` method only accepts unwrapped objects

Answer (score 7):

You can convert `UIImage` to `NSData` and pass it to this method

```
func getArrayOfBytesFromImage(imageData:NSData) -> NSMutableArray
{

    // the number of elements:
    let count = imageData.length / sizeof(UInt8)

    // create array of appropriate length:
    var bytes = [UInt8](count: count, repeatedValue: 0)

    // copy bytes into array
    imageData.getBytes(&bytes, length:count * sizeof(UInt8))

    var byteArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        byteArray.addObject(NSNumber(unsignedChar: bytes[i]))
    }

    return byteArray


}
```

Comment: how can i perform reverse...how can i get image from bytes

Comment: get your image back from the array of bytes ---> 


static func getImag(from bytes: [NSNumber]) -> UIImage? {
        return UIImage.init(data: Data.init(bytes: bytes.map({ $0.uint8Value })))
    }

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5, iOS 14 version based on [toofani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1782153/toofani) answer, minimal changes

```
func getArrayOfBytesFromImage(imageData:NSData) -> Array<UInt8>
{

  // the number of elements:
  let count = imageData.length / MemoryLayout<Int8>.size

  // create array of appropriate length:
  var bytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: count)

  // copy bytes into array
  imageData.getBytes(&bytes, length:count * MemoryLayout<Int8>.size)

  var byteArray:Array = Array<UInt8>()

  for i in 0 ..< count {
    byteArray.append(bytes[i])
  }

  return byteArray


}
```

So a complete sequence looks like this... assuming I got a UIImage I extract the data and then recombine it.

```
let data = imageX.pngData()
bytes = getArrayOfBytesFromImage(imageData: data! as NSData) 
let datos: NSData = NSData(bytes: bytes, length: bytes.count)
newImage = UIImage(data: datos as Data) // Note it's optional. Don't force unwrap!!!
```

Comment: What if I just want raw data and not pngData.  pngData seems to change the bytes so it thinks it is a png image.

Comment: I think you need to convert it to png data because Apple is not going to publish their internal formats for you to play around with.

Answer (score 0):

Little modifying for @user3069232

We can pass the image and compression parameter to get byte array.

```
func getByteArrayForImage(_ image: UIImage, compression: CGFloat = 1.0) -> Array<UInt8> {
        guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: compression) as? NSData else { return [] }
        let count = imageData.length / MemoryLayout<Int8>.size
        
        var bytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: count)
        imageData.getBytes(&bytes, length:count * MemoryLayout<Int8>.size)
        var byteArray = Array<UInt8>()
        for byte in bytes {
            byteArray.append(byte)
        }
        return byteArray
    }
```