# Change UIImage to array or matrix in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I been trying to convert an UIImage to a matrix or a bitarray in swift but I don`t know how

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let bgimg = UIImage(named: "IMG_8565.JPG") // The image used as a background
let bgimgview = UIImageView(image: bgimg) // Create the view holding the image
bgimgview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500) // The size of the background image

let frontimg = UIImage(named: "spongebob.png") // The image in the foreground
let frontimgview = UIImageView(image: frontimg) // Create the view holding the image
frontimgview.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 150, height: 150) // The size and position of the front image

bgimgview.addSubview(frontimgview) // Add the front image on top of the background
```

the last line contains the image and is what i`m trying to change into a matrix or a bitarray

also I know there are similar post but i hardly understand them, so please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert UIImage to byte array in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734059/convert-uiimage-to-byte-array-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

mb you want just convert your image to the Data?

```
guard let image = UIImage(named: "IMG_8565.JPG") else { return }
guard let data = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) else { return }
```

compressionQuality: 1.0 - it's max quality for your image.

Comment: No, I need to convert the UIImage into a matrix to be able to display it as that, a matrix